# Python string as file in Skimage imread

Tags: python, file, decode, scikit-image

I am doing the CIFAR challenge on Kaggle.

They gave a .7z file that contains 50k pictures as train. It took me 1 hour to unzip it and then another 40 mins to read all the file and put it on memory.

Trying not to create the 50k files, as this is the bottleneck of this, I have installed the pylzma and other libraries but all of them will tell me that the file is not valid.

The 7z from bash, can read the file properly, and list the files. So I used the `Popen` to uncompress all the files and put it in a string in memory using the bash 7z program

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["7z", "e", "-so", "awa.7z"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I have managed to get each file individually by looking at its size and then getting the appropriate bytes from the string

```
f1 = p[0][0:2105]
```

What I want now is trick Python to think that F1 file pointer, so that I can call the skimage.io.imread and it will convert to its appropriate structures. Or maybe just pass the memory values to skimage and it will convert it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing through the skimage code, I have found that they could make integration with PIL, another image library. That library has a function to get the image info straight from an open file pointer.

In my case, the file pointer is a StringIO, so it could read the data and identify what is it about.

mhawke, thank for your help. It seems to me that your solution will work as well, but I don't want to deal with the image data itself.

I have put the code in the github (its just an skeleton, but working), if anybody is interested, here goes the fancy page
http://adrianow.github.io/7z_on_array/

Below a short part of the solution:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

# begin and end of each file
low = 0
up = 0
images = [0] *len(p_f_list)

# get each file from the byte file
for i, f in enumerate(p_f_list):
    up += int(f[0])
    # get bytes from the array
    raw_img = p_f_data.data[low:up]
    low = up

    # Convert rawImage to Mat
    pil_image = Image.open(StringIO(raw_img))
    np_image = np.array(pil_image)
    images[i] = np_image
```

Comment: By using `imread.imread_from_blob()` you are not dealing with the image data any more than using `skimage.io.imread()` nor the PIL code that you posted above - all three return a numpy array. IMO using the `imread` package directly is better than PIL because the package will always be available due to it being a dependency of `skimage.io.imread()` (the plugin code simply delegates the processing to `imread.imread()`)

Comment: You are right about the fact of that the package will be there. What I meant about not dealing with the image is knowing if it is a png or jpg. I know that the first bytes of a png is PNG, not sure about JPG.

Comment: Oh, I see. The Python standard library provides the function [`imghdr.what()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what), which detects more file types than does `PIL.Image.open()`. Alternatively, you can just pass the file name extension to `imread.imread_from_blob()`. BTW `cStringIO` is faster than `StringIO` which might be important in your case.

Comment: Thanks! Will use that.

Answer (score 9):

Though doc of skimage.io.imread says the first parameter is a string for filename, I found it also accepts file-like object (with skimage of version 0.10.0).

So you may read image data into memory like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

with open(filename) as f:
    img_data = f.read()
decoded_img_data = skimage.io.imread(StringIO(img_data))
print decoded_img_data

>> OUTPUT:
array([[[235, 230, 234],
        [233, 228, 232],
        [231, 226, 230],
        ...,
```

Comment: Love it. Thanks!!  Who would've thought to *not* RTFD. Though, I suspect this only works because it uses PIL as its default image handling "plugin", so this might not work in general.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to `skimage.io.imread()` is the name of an image file from which to read, so you won't be able to trick it using image data held in a string. Options (in order of convenience):

- use the [`imread`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imread/) package directly - see `imread.imread_from_blob()`. This returns a `numpy.ndarray` (same as `skimage.io.imread`). You need to know the image file type (jpg, png, gif, etc.) as this must be passed as the second argument:

  ```
  from imread import imread_from_blob
  img_data = imread_from_blob(f1, 'jpg')

  >>> img_data
  array([[[ 23, 123, 149],
  [ 22, 120, 147],
  [ 22, 118, 143],
  ...,
  etc.
  ```
- write the data to a temporary file then open that temp file with `imread()`. `imread()` does this itself when handling a URL.
- use a named pipe. Open the pipe for reading with `imread()`, then write the data to the pipe. You may need threads or multiprocessing to do this.